# Matching jq var inside curly quotes

Tags: templates, variables, jq

I am trying to replace "${FOO}" with "BAR" (please note: "${FOO}" is NOT a shell variable - this is how it appears in the json, and I have no control over the json)

This works:

```
echo '{ "name": "${FOO}" }' | \
    jq '.|(select (.name == "${FOO}") | .name) |= "BAR"'

{
  "name": "BAR"
}
```

However, if I want to programatically assign the matching value (`MYVAR=FOO` in this case),I cannot get it to work e.g.

```
echo '{ "name": "${FOO}" }' | \
    jq --arg MYVAR FOO '.|(select (.name == "${$MYVAR}") | .name) |= "BAR"'
{
  "name": "${FOO}"
}
```

My gut feel is that it's the quotes around the matching string that's the problem, as this also works:

```
echo '{ "name": "FOO" }' | \
    jq --arg MYVAR FOO '.|(select (.name == $MYVAR) | .name) |= "BAR"'
{
    "name": "BAR"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you never need an initial `.|` as `.` here is just the "identity" filter.

Second, it's important to distinguish between shell variables on the one hand and jq $-variables on the other.  Unless you explicitly tie the two together, they have completely independent lives.  As you discovered, using `--arg MYVAR FOO` sets the jq variable `$MYVAR` to the JSON string `"FOO"`; to reference this variable, you simply write `$MYVAR` in the jq program.

It's also fine to initialize the jq variable using:

```
--arg MYVAR "${MYVAR}"
```

This sets the jq-variable to the (string) value of the shell variable.

Third, the names of jq "$-variables" are highly constrained: excluding the initial "$", they must match the regex: [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*

Thus if your real goal is to change occurrences of the JSON string
"${FOO}" with "BAR", where FOO is to be specified programmatically,
you will have to adopt a different strategy. This
would work:

```
echo '{ "name": "${FOO}" }' |
  jq -c --arg MYVAR FOO --arg MYVALUE BAR '
    if .name == "${\($MYVAR)}" then .name = $MYVALUE else . end'
```

This produces: {"name":"BAR"}

See also the section ["Using jq as a template engine"](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook#using-jq-as-a-template-engine) in the [jq Cookbook](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook).

Comment: Hi peak, thank you for your help and tips (learning new things about jq each day)

Unfortunately, your answer did not really work for me
I suspect there was confusion in my opening question, so I have now edited that to avoid any confusion

The "${MYVAR}" string in the json is NOT a bash var - that is how the string appears in the json, and I have no control over that

When I modify your suggestion (as below) I *still* get "${MYVAR}" value for "name"

    echo '{ "name": "${FOO}" }' | jq -c --arg MYVAR FOO 'if .name == "${MYVAR}" then .name = $MYVAR else . end'

Comment: And in trying to clear up confusion with my prev comment, I have only introduced more confusion (and cannot edit comment after 5 mins - grrr) - take 2...
The "${FOO}" string in the json is NOT a bash var - that is how the string appears in the json, and I have no control over that When I modify your suggestion (as below) I still get "${FOO}" value for "name" echo '{ "name": "${FOO}" }' | jq -c --arg MYVAR FOO 'if .name == "${MYVAR}" then .name = $MYVAR else . end'

Comment: In your suggestion, your check is specifically testing for the string literal "${MYVAR}" (which is what you have put into the json) - it is not testing for "${" + valueof($MYVAR) + "}" i.e. the input JSON is different to mine, and is always testing for that string literal, and NOT the value of $MYVAR

Again, many thanks for your help

Comment: I've revised Part 3 of the answer to reflect the clarifications in your comments.

Comment: Perfect!
Thank you so much peak